# How can I set a top limit for the PCM value when changing the loudness with pulseaudio?

Tags: alsa, pulseaudio

when I change the loudness with pulseaudio, pulseaudio acts on several of the values I can see when I use `alsamixer -c0`

I have a problem: when the PCM loudness exceeds a certain value (80%), the sound crackles (or soaks? I don't know if this is the word).

I'd like to make sure the PCM value is fixed to 80%, so that pulseaudio only changes the value of the "Front" channel.

How can I achieve that?

My configuration: Fedora, KDE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this, it took me a while to find so I post it here in case it might help others.

Edit the file:

```
/etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Look for the line:

```
load-module module-udev-detect
```

And change it into:

```
load-module module-udev-detect ignore_dB=1
```

Comment: I'm unable to make the sound crackle again (this topic is quite old), so I'll say you must be right and accept your answer.